# Cannot align a portion of text in a UI Tooltip?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tooltip

I have a Jquery UI Tooltip which has multiple rows of data.  Each row has 2 separate pieces of information that I want to align separately to format nicely.  The name on the left side I want to align left, while the data associated with the name I want to align to the right.

I have tried all sorts of ways to align, with no success.

I read that I can use the `ui-tooltip-content` css class https://api.jqueryui.com/tooltip/#option-classes

to manipulate the content, which works successfully if I am manipulating the entire content itself; however I am trying to manipulate a span tag within the content.

By doing

```
  .ui-tooltip-content .right
  {

      color:blue;
  }
```

I am successfully able to change only that text blue; however if I try

```
 text-align: end;
  text-align-last: end;
  align-content: flex-end;
  align-items: flex-end;
  align-self: flex-end;
```

(I tried "right,""flex-end, and "end").

none of them seem to work

I am curious if anyone has any idea on how I may be able to align my text properly so that I wont have an issue?  In reality I can just leave the default `text-align: left;` for the main content, but I just need to find out how to right align the right portion of the text.

Thank you for any help

Comment: Give `margin-left: auto` a shot.

Comment: @AndyHoffman thank you for the suggestion.  Unfortunately this doesn't work in either `ui-tooltip`, `ui-tooltip-content`, or the `span` tag's class for either `margin-left(or right):auto;`  Hopefully there is a way to accomplish what I want to do.  The children of the content definitely get style updates, I'm just not sure why alignment isn't working at all.  Thanks again!

Comment: Hi, Try adding below css
 .ui-tooltip-content .right
  {
     float:right;
      color:blue;
text-align:right
  }

Comment: @KKGupta by adding `float` everything actually seems to be working!  Thank you very much!  Can you provide an answer so that I can upvote you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding below CSS:

```
.ui-tooltip-content .right { 
  float:right; 
  color:blue; 
  text-align:right 
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  Float:right is what helped me position the content, the others didn't matter.